# Azure Function - Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: java

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have Azure function which is written using Java. This was working properly up to date when deployed to the function app and locally. Suddenly there was an error indicating on the Azure function log, This still works perfectly on the local machine but not when deployed to the Azure function app.

```
2024-02-09T02:41:37Z   [Verbose]   Handling WorkerErrorEvent for runtime:java, workerId:java. Failed with: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.WorkerProcessExitException: /usr/lib/jvm/msft-11-x64/bin/java exited with code 134 (0x86)
 ---> System.Exception
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2024-02-09T02:41:37Z   [Verbose]   Attempting to dispose webhost or jobhost channel for workerId: 'x', runtime: 'java'
2024-02-09T02:41:37Z   [Verbose]   Disposing language worker channel with id:x
2024-02-09T02:41:37Z   [Verbose]   Disposed language worker channel with id:x
2024-02-09T02:41:37Z   [Verbose]   No initialized worker channels for runtime 'java'. Delaying future invocations
2024-02-09T02:41:37Z   [Verbose]   Restarting worker channel for runtime: 'java'
2024-02-09T02:41:37Z   [Error]   Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:java. Shutting down and proactively recycling the Functions Host to recover
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   #
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   #
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007c9f44fc1d17 (sent by kill), pid=72, tid=104
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   #
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-8519785 (11.0.21+9) (build 11.0.21+9-LTS)
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-8519785 (11.0.21+9-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, serial gc, linux-amd64)
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   # Problematic frame:
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   # J 1366 c1 java.lang.invoke.VarForm.getMemberName(I)Ljava/lang/invoke/MemberName; java.base@11.0.21 (21 bytes) @ 0x00007c9f44fc1d17 [0x00007c9f44fc1cc0+0x0000000000000057]
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   #
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   # Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h" (or dumping to /home/site/wwwroot/core.72)
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   #
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   # An error report file with more information is saved as:
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   # /tmp/hs_err_pid72.log
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   Compiled method (c1)    9133 1366       1       java.lang.invoke.VarForm::getMemberName (21 bytes)
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]    total in heap  [0x00007c9f44fc1b10,0x00007c9f44fc1ef0] = 992
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]    relocation     [0x00007c9f44fc1c88,0x00007c9f44fc1cc0] = 56
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]    main code      [0x00007c9f44fc1cc0,0x00007c9f44fc1e00] = 320
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]    stub code      [0x00007c9f44fc1e00,0x00007c9f44fc1e40] = 64
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]    metadata       [0x00007c9f44fc1e40,0x00007c9f44fc1e48] = 8
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]    scopes data    [0x00007c9f44fc1e48,0x00007c9f44fc1e68] = 32
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]    scopes pcs     [0x00007c9f44fc1e68,0x00007c9f44fc1ed8] = 112
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]    dependencies   [0x00007c9f44fc1ed8,0x00007c9f44fc1ee0] = 8
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]    nul chk table  [0x00007c9f44fc1ee0,0x00007c9f44fc1ef0] = 16
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   Could not load hsdis-amd64.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   #
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   #   https://github.com/microsoft/openjdk/issues
2024-02-09T02:44:03Z   [Information]   #
```

As per the above log, I checked the hs_err_pid72.log it seems this is like a JVM crash.

I check the following application configurations too.

```
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
"FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
```

It seems those configs are also in order and no changes since ever I built and deployed the function app.looking for an way to recover this

Comment: Modify the JDK version of the function app. Restart the function app and run again.

Comment: Already restart and check no change

Comment: which JDK version are you using?

Comment: JDK 11 is set on Configuration > General settings

Comment: This was perfectly working earlier and suddenly got this error

Comment: Can you set it to JDK 17 and check once

Comment: I set the JDK to 17 and checked. Now I'm getting the below error  [Error]   prod-3a632fce-c836-4189-a02d-f490c22850e2: User message handler complete: Message: SequenceNumber: 41267, Exception: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.TestTrigger
 ---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.WorkerProcessExitException: /usr/lib/jvm/msft-17-x64/bin/java exited with code 134 (0x86)
 ---> System.Exception
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker.

Comment: This could be due to JDK version incompatibility with the code. Can you revert back to JDK 11 and check if still the issue persists.

Comment: yes still exists. It still shows the original error that I got earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This was able to be fixed after changing back to JDK version 11 (it was originally on JDK 11) on Azure Function APP(Configuration > General settings) and Performing Advanced Application Restart through Function App. (Diagnose and Resolve Problem > Diagnostic Tools > Advanced Application Restart). This has caused due to a JVM crash.